# Duplicate catalog product list

Tags: blocks, cms-block

I need to customize the list display only for the home page.
I've duplicated **catalog/produtcs/list.phtml** to **catalog/produtcs/list_home.phtml** and in the home page content, in the CMS section of the admin I've added the code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_home" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="produtos_home" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

But that just didn't load anything. How do I register this "new" block?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the block with the alias `catalog/product_list_home` exist?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm noob with Magento, where do I create it?

Comment: What products are you trying to display on the homepage? Is there a special category that contains these products?

Comment: The last 8 products, no specific category.

Answer (score 1):

To create the collection for the latest 8 products, in `list_home.phtml` replace this (should be at the start of the file):

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

with this:

```
$_productCollection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()                   
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');   
$_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(8);
```

Then in your CMS page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_home" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="produtos_home" column_count="4" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

Please take note of the `column_count="4"` parameter inside the block declaration, you can change this to suit your theme.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new module for that.
Let's call it `Easylife_Homepage`. Create these files:

`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Homepage.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Homepage>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Homepage>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Homepage/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Homepage>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Homepage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <easylife_homepage>
                <class>Easylife_Homepage_Block</class>
            </easylife_homepage>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Homepage/Block/Homepage.php` - your block that gets the last added products

```
<?php
class Easylife_Homepage_Block_Homepage  extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCT_LIMIT = 8;
    protected $_products = null;
    public function getProductLimit()
    {
        return $this->getDataSetDefault('product_limit', self::DEFAULT_PRODUCT_LIMIT);
    }
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_products)) {
            $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addUrlRewrite()
                ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC')
                ->setPage(1, $this->getProductLimit());
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
            $this->_products = $products;
        }
        return $this->_products;
    }
}
```

Now clear the cache and add this to the homepage content

```
{{block type="easylife_homepage/homepage" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

Save and enjoy.
If you later decide you don't want 8 products but you want 10 just modify what you added in the homepage content to this:

```
{{block type="easylife_homepage/homepage" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml" product_limit="10"}}
```